# Get daily stock movement in %

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

My goal is to get daily stock movement in % as follows in `Google Sheets`:

```
name  1JAN 2JAN 3JAN 4JAN 5JAN 
------------------------------
GOOG  1%   2%   1%   2%   1%  
BABA  2%   1%   3%   5%   6%
```

Can anyone pls advice. I am new to Google finance.

Comment: @Rob. Thanks for pointing out. Can you tell me what specific guideline does this question violates?

Comment: Clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

See [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O7vCJiAhusxtyBn6aP579xA7ayY_5xmJIvasOULh5Zk/edit?usp=sharing)

How it works:

- Input the desired dates and tickers. Tickers go across row 3.
  [image]
- Date will populate in 'getData' sheet. The formulas are made to be easily copy/pasted without any additional editing. Look at the change formula column C/F and feel free to edit the formula if this is not what you are looking for.
  [image]
- 'reFormat' sheet will format your data according to your screenshot. Again the formulas are made to be easily copy/pasted or dragged across/down.
  [image]